# Basic Plot - How to use text labels on X axis?

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels

Can you use text as X axis labels on a plot? I've searched and cannot see any examples. Am I trying to do something that is not possible in R? Even when I try to plot one variable. `Countries` is text/character - but I do not know how to set it as such

```
plot(Finally$Countries,Finally$RobberyPerCent, pch = 16, col = 2)
```

I get the error

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Thank you, my goal is to combine two variables and see if there is a basic pattern. I've been able to figure out simple linear regression (no correlation), but I'm failing at basic plotting

```
#Subset for Percentages
Q5DataFinal <- subset(Q5Data, select = c(RobberyPerCent, UnlawfulPerCent))
View(Q5DataFinal)
library(data.table)
Nearlythere <- setDT(Q5DataFinal, keep.rownames = TRUE)[] # turn rownames into column data
names(Nearlythere)[names(Nearlythere) == 'rn'] <- 'Countries'     #renaming rn to countries
Nearlythere$Countries[] <- lapply(Nearlythere$Countries, as.character) #Changing Countries to Character
Finally <- Nearlythere
summary(Finally) #Countries saved as characters


# Attempt to create two Y axis Graph with Countries as X ticks
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)              # Additional space for second y-axis
plot(Finally$Countries,Finally$RobberyPerCent, pch = 16, col = 2)              # Create first plot
par(new = TRUE)                             # Add new plot
plot(Finally$Countries, Finally$UnlawfulPerCent, pch = 17, col = 3,              # Create second plot without axes
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(range(Finally$UnlawfulPerCent)))      # Add second axis
mtext("UnlawfulPerCent", side = 4, line = 3)             # Add second axis label
```

Dput is

```
structure(list(Countries = list("Albania", "Austria", "Bulgaria", 
    "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Finland", "Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)", 
    "Greece", "Ireland", "Italy", "Kosovo (under United Nations Security Council Resolution 1244/99)", 
    "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Montenegro", 
    "Romania", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Switzerland"), 
    RobberyPerCent = c(5, 6, 18, 7, 5, 23, 5, 9, 24, 9, 40, 12, 
    17, 18, 10, 52, 24, 33, 10, 17, 80, 2), UnlawfulPerCent = c(95, 
    94, 82, 93, 95, 77, 95, 91, 76, 91, 60, 88, 83, 82, 90, 48, 
    76, 67, 90, 83, 20, 98)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000020282d01ef0>)
```

Comment: Try `plot(Basta$RobberyPerCent ~ factor(Basta$Countries))`?

Comment: Thank you @xilliam it gave the error ```Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1' ``` I converted the Countries column to character

Comment: Would be better to post your data object by copy-pasting the console output of `dput(Basta)` into your question.

Comment: @xilliam I apologise - there were problems in the original code I sent - Basta is now replaced with Finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
 par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
 x <- seq(0, 5, length.out = 500)
 plot(x, sin(x^2), xaxt = "n", xlab = expression("Here is X"), ylab = expression(sin(x^2)),
      main = expression("My coolest plot" - sin(x^2)))
 axis(1, at=0:5, labels=c("Albania", "Kosovo", "Kongo", "Germany", "Bulgaria", "Spain"))
```

[image]

*An addition*

---

```
#your dataset
countries <- list("Albania", "Austria", "Bulgaria", 
                  "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Finland", "Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)", 
                  "Greece", "Ireland", "Italy", "Kosovo (under United Nations Security Council Resolution 1244/99)", 
                  "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Montenegro", 
                  "Romania", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Switzerland")

#modify to
axis(1, at=0:21, labels=countries, cex.axis=0.5) #select cex.axis for better displaying
```

---

Comment: On the X axis - instead of 0 to 5 I am looking to add in the Country Names from Column ```Countries``` so 0 would be Albania and 22 would be Spain. Thank you

Comment: @iKcon See, i add what you need ;) You can correct for your case.

Comment: Thank you @manro I am working through it to try to adapt your solution - I want to use the column ```Countries``` instead of typing in the ```c("Albania,...etc)``` - I am failing there. Next step will be to adapt your formula to my dataframe

Comment: @iKcon look, i corrected.  I think you should cut to ```Germany``` and ```Kosovo```. Better to make a comment under the plot.